# What is the best way to clean up the spider webs?

Tags: cleaning, home, dust, fire

In our family house, the spider web is really a kind of a mess. We have tried a lot of things:

- Brooms aren't good, after a little while the webs are all over it and it takes a while to clean them again (so it is not possible to sweep with them again)
- Duster is similar, it is nearly impossible to clean it after.
- Then I used something like the thing in the picture, but it doesn't remove the webs, it only throws them down.
- I had idea about using fire on my mind, but I am not sure if it is safe and how it will work (there is a problem that the webs are often pretty high)

I would be grateful for any hacks for this.

[image: spider web remover]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use the vacuum cleaner, with the long tube but without a brush.

When most of the spiderweb has been removed you can use the duster or the item in your picture to remove the leftover bits, keep your dust sucker near to take care of cleaning the duster and/or the fallen bits of web.

For a real nasty situation, you can use your duster or your 'photo item' and cover them with an old panty hose, which will allow you to take off all spiderweb rests in one go. Take that hose off and bin it.

If available, also use a spare pair of eyes, as two see so much more than one. And if your helper is like mine, you take turns in cleaning and spotting, helping with the amount you need to do.

Very bad situations, like cleaning out where there are many live webs, the method of using a piece of wood will work well.
It does not need to be wood, any stick shaped item that is long enough will work, if working outside a rough branch will be best. But inside a house with paint or wallpaper you should not touch the walls with something that is likely to leave tracks.

Answer (score 2):

I did it today. I had to clean lots of spider's web. The best thing is to use a piece of wood and just hover it, the web sticks to the wood. You don't need to clean the wood just keep doing it in other areas. You may need to turn the wood so more web sticks to it.

Although the tip of the wood was full of web as big as a lid of a jar it was still grabbing more and more webs. Once you drag that on every corner, the remains can be cleaned quickly with vacuum cleaner.